# Setting input value with JQuery doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, single-page-application

These questions are from looking at the single page app sample [located here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2/tree/master/TodoSPA). Can anyone explain why attempts to set the value of an input control with JQuery does/does not work with the following conditions? I will include the HTML that is constant and then present a series of Javascript lines that I can't explain the behavior. First the HTML.

```
<form>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="data-container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Region</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control request-region" id="regionfield" value="test" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

1. If I run this code it works as expected and the input box has a value of 99. Note that I'm setting the value in two different places because of the issue I found in the next sample.

```
$("#regionfield").val(44);
var $entry = $("div").find(".data-container");
$entry.find("#regionfield").val(99);
```

2. But if I remove that first line of code and just run this below the value of the input is "test". Why does setting the value fail now when it worked in the first instance?

```
var $entry = $("div").find(".data-container");
$entry.find("#regionfield").val(99);
```

3. Now if I save the HTML from the first code into a string, empty the control, then load it back, why does this code not result in the updated value of 99 but instead has the original value of "test"?

```
$("#regionfield").val(44);
var $entry = $("div").find(".data-container");
$entry.find("#regionfield").val(99);
var output = '';
output += $entry.html();
$entry.empty();
$entry.html(output);
```

**Update** I just noticed that I get different results when testing with `Bootply` vs `Codeply`. With `Bootply` the result for code sample #1 is 99 but on `Codeply` the result is "test". This makes me suspect the behavior is related to Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

### **Simple Explanation**:

The value **attribute** and the value **property** are not the same and are not connected outside of the initial load.

The value attribute is stored in the markup. This is what is initially rendered by the Browser. Unlike other properties, any subsequent changes to `value` through JavaScript are stored within the DOM itself.

The attribute/your markup is **not updated** when the value on the element is changed during the course of your application.

This means that because you're grabbing the **markup** as your test, you'll never see the `value` **attribute** change, but if you were to look at the actual DOM node you would see the current and correct value underneath the value **property**.

---

### Longer Explanation:

Attributes in the Specification are called IDL 's and can be either reflective or non-reflective.

[For more information see the HTML Standard here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes)

A DOM Node's `property` and its HTML `attribute` are interchangeable from the point of rendering if the node is not altered - but also if **specific** attributes are changed.

Altering `id` and `class` in any way, whether directly on the DOM Node or within the Attribute object using the `element.setAttribute` method, will result in *both* values being changed.

`id` and `class` are **reflective** IDL attributes because they, in effect, watch their content attributes for changes and vice versa.

Alternatively `checked` and `value` IDL attributes are **not reflective**. When the `value` or `checked` properties are altered on either the DOM Node or the Attribute Object, it does not alter the corresponding attributes of the other.
*Outside of those properties*( there are more than `id` and `class` - though there's no real list of reflective vs not reflective - I would presume it's any property related to the identity of the Node in the DOM that would cause a re-render ) the **content attributes** and **DOM Node properties** are not bound together.

This makes using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` useless if the intent is to update or get *current data*, because the *current data* is only found within the **DOM Node properties**.

Likewise, if you are trying to gauge whether a change in the value property has occurred by looking at the **markup** you will only see the original value.

Comment: I've just noticed that my sample code listed under #1 acts different between Bootply and Codeply. In Bootply the screen will render 99 for the value. In Codeply the screen always shows "test". Perhaps the behavior is related to Bootstrap.